# Python Hydra configuration for different environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, fb-hydra

### Background

I currently have a script which does some API data gathering. The script is deployed to two environments, `test` and `user`. Each environment has different settings which I have created the respective configuration files. I am currently migrating my project to use the `hydra-core` package.

### Objective

If possible I would like configure Hydra as such. Load all the configuration files from either the `test` or `user`. The default should be the `test` environment unless specified via CLI to load the `user` environment.

### Current Configuration Structure

```
Project Root
|
├── config
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── config1.yaml
│   │   ├── config2.yaml
│   │   ├── config3.yaml
│   │   └── config4.yaml
│   └── user
│       ├── config1.yaml
│       ├── config2.yaml
│       ├── config3.yaml
│       └── config4.yaml
```

### Current Default Configuration - config.yaml

```yaml
defaults:
  - test: [config1.yaml, config2.yaml, config3.yaml, config4.yaml]
```

How would I override the above default via the CLI?

Comment: Side note: you don't need `.yaml` in your defaults list or when you override a config group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a config group, e.g. `env` that would contain configs with the default lists you want to use for each environment.

```
├── config
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── env
│   │   ├── user.yaml
│   │   └── test.yaml
│   ├── test
│   │   └── user.yaml
│   └── user
│       └── config1.yaml
```

env/user.yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
 - /user/config1
 - /user/config2
```

env/test.yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
 - /test/config1
 - /test/config2
```

Primary config.yaml:

```
defaults:
 - env: test # Overridable
```

With the above, you should be able to override the environment like:

```sh
$ python foo.py env=user
```

This is similar to the [configure experiment](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/) pattern.
This is relying on recursive default lists, new in Hydra 1.1. You can learn more about them [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/)

Comment: Based on my current implementation, I already have split them into the different `env` which is like a config group. How would I specify via CLI which `env` to use? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer and added another link. Please read both links before implementing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have tested it and works just as I wanted.