# Set Hydra enviroment with uvicorn/fastapi

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, fb-hydra

I have a FastAPI application that is going to production soon, however i am facing some problems with hydra integration.

First i could not run the `@hydra.main()` decorator on fastAPI endpoints. This was overcome with using the Hydra Compose API. Here is my implementation for it:

```
def load_config(config_path, config_name):
    """Loads specified hydra config.

    This method is used because, fastapi and hydra did not
    wanna work together.
    """
    core.global_hydra.GlobalHydra.instance().clear()
    initialize(version_base=None, config_path=config_path)
    cfg = compose(config_name=config_name)

    return cfg
```

This was fine until now, while I only used one config, but now I need to separate test and production configurations.
My configuration dircetory structure looks like this:

```
├── config
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── env
│   │   ├── prod.yaml
│   │   └── test.yaml
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── prod1.yaml
│   └── test
│       └── test1.yaml
```

The directory structure and file contents are based on this post:
[Python Hydra configuration for different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210571/python-hydra-configuration-for-different-environments). The default environment is set to test.

My application runs with this command:
`uvicorn my.api:app` and this successfully loads the test config.
However when I try to run it with:
`uvicorn env=prod my.api:app` the test config still loads instead of production. Here i want to load the prod configuration.
How can I achieve this?
I have found this related github issue, but the solution was not clear from it: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/204

To be clear, i am willing to make fundamental changes if the problem lies within not using `@hydra.main()`

Answer (score 2):

The Compose API does not integrate with the command line. You need to pass the overrides yourself on the call site.
Check the example in the [Compose API page](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/compose_api/) again, in particular the `overrides` parameter.

```py
from hydra import compose, initialize
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # context initialization
    with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="conf", job_name="test_app"):
        cfg = compose(config_name="config", overrides=["db=mysql", "db.user=me"])
        print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
```